# Text to string array and delete duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, string

The idea of the program is that it gets the text divided by space from the scanner.

I need to write a method to create an array from text, delete duplicates and return an array of the words which are used only once and don't have duplicates.

I can't find out how to make a new array of unique words. Using only simple and basic construction without *HashSet* etc.*

For example:

```
a b a b c a b d
```

result:

```
c d
```

```java
public static String Dublicate(String text) { 
    String[] dublic = text.split(" ");
    String result="";
    for (int i = 0; i < dublic.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < dublic.length; j++)
            if (dublic[i].equals(dublic[j]))
                dublic[j] = "delete";
    }
    for (String s: dublic) {
        if (s !="delete") {
            result =result + s + " ";  
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Answer (score 1):

**Split By Space**

For splitting by space we can use the **split()** method & can pass the Space string (**""**) in the parameter.

```
String[] texts = text.split(" ");
```

**Delete The duplicate elements**

If We can use java 1.8 or greater than 1.8, we can use stream API for getting distinct elements like.

```
Arrays.stream(texts).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Or if we need to implement it with java 1.7, we can use HashSet for getting distinct elements like.

```
String[] distinctElements = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(texts)).toArray(new String[0]);
```

**The final Source code can be like this:**

```
public static String[] textToArray1_7(String text) {
        //split by space
        String[] texts = text.split(" ");
        //Distinct value
        return Arrays.stream(texts).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    public static String[] textToArray1_8(String text) {
        //split by space
        String[] texts = text.split(" ");
        //Distinct value
        return  new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(texts)).toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

If any further question, can ask for more clarification.

Comment: You've misread the question: the goal is not to return distinct elements, but only elements that are present only once.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to mark i-th element as duplicate in case when it really is. See my comments in the below code

```java
public static String Dublicate(String text) {
    String[] dublic = text.split(" ");
    String result="";
    for (int i=0; i<dublic.length; i++){
        if (dublic[i].equals("delete")) { // Minor optimization: 
            // skip elements that are already marked
            continue;
        }
        boolean isDub = false;   // we need to track i-th element
        for(int j=i+1; j<dublic.length; j++) {
            if (dublic[i].equals(dublic[j])) {
                dublic[j] = "delete";
                isDub = true;   // i-th element is also a duplicate...
            }
        }
        if (isDub) {
            dublic[i] = "delete";  // ...so you should also mark it
        }
    }
    for(String s: dublic){
        if(!s.equals("delete")) { // for strings you should use "!equals" instead of "!="
            result = result + s + " ";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

P.S. if original text contains "delete" the result will be incorrect since you use "delete" as a reserved marker word

Answer (score 0):

If *the array of unique strings* needs to be returned, then the initial array of strings after the splitting the input has to be compacted to exclude invalid values, and a smaller copy needs to be returned:

```java
public static String[] uniques(String text) { 
    String[] words = text.split(" ");

    int p = 0; // index/counter of unique elements
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String curr = words[i];
        if (null == curr) {
            continue;
        }
        boolean dupFound = false;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) {
            if (null == words[j]) {
                continue;
            }
            if (curr.equals(words[j])) {
                words[j] = null;
                dupFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (dupFound) {
            words[i] = null;
        } else {
            words[p++] = words[i]; // shift unique elements to the start of array
        }
    }
    
    return Arrays.copyOf(words, p);
}
```

If the array of unique strings is returned, it may be conveniently converted into String using `String::join` as shown below in the test.
Test:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(uniques("a b a b c a b d")));
System.out.println(String.join(" ", uniques("a b a b c a b d")));
```

Output

```
[c, d]
c d
```